# previous pay period using dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I am very new to power bi and power query and while I have searched for a solution, I may be so new that I am unaware that a similar solution is here and could solve my issue but here goes.

I have been tasked with taking a table of data (which I don't have access to alter) and display in Power BI current pay period data along side data from the previous pay period (essentially doing an Excel vlookup for the previous period (each pay period is 14 days apart)) and then creating calculations to show the change in position vacancy from one pay period to the next. I only have Power Query and Power BI in which to make this happen. I created a key from different columns and then a linked a referenced table to pull the previous dates info but this didn't work once I started putting slicers on the matrix.  Right now I'm trying to assign each pay period a identifier which grows by one with each later date (completed) and then create a column which reads the table and gives the previous pay period vacancy hours.

| Empl Number | Sched Hours | Budg Hours | Vacant Hours | Pay Period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.00 | 9.00 | 9.00 | 01/01/2022 |
| 2 | 22.5 | 22.5 | 0.00 | 01/01/2022 |
| 2 | 0.00 | 22.5 | 22.5 | 01/15/2022 |
| 3 | 0.00 | 37.5 | 37.5 | 01/01/2022 |
| 3 | 37.5 | 37.5 | 0.00 | 01/15/2022 |
| 3 | 37.5 | 37.5 | 0.00 | 01/29/2022 |

I am expecting to see something like the image below in Power BI:

| Pay Period | Total Vacant Hours | Vacant Hour Change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 46.5 |  |
| 01/15/2022 | 60.0 | 13.5 |
| 01/29/2022 | 0.00 | -60.0 |
| 02/12/2022 | 0.00 | 0.00 |

Comment: Please edit your post to show your original data as text which can be copy/pasted.  And also post a screenshot of your expected results from the data you provide.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the picture of your data. Would you also be able to add this sample data in a table format so that answerers can copy/paste more easily?

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post

Comment: there is no ``02/12/2022`` in your sample data...

Answer (score 0):

In Power Query: *(Read the comments to understand the algorithm)*

```
let

//Change next line to reflect your actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table8"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Empl Number", Int64.Type}, {"Sched Hours", type number}, {"Budg Hours", type number}, 
        {"Vacant Hours", type number}, {"Pay Period", type date}}),

//Group by pay period and aggregate Sum of Vacant Hours
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Pay Period"}, {
        {"Vacant Hours", each List.Sum([Vacant Hours]), type nullable number}}),

//Add a column which is a "shifted" vacant hours column
//  This will put this and previous pay period on same row
    #"Shifted Vacant Hours" = Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(#"Grouped Rows") & {{null} & List.RemoveLastN(#"Grouped Rows"[Vacant Hours],1)},
        type table[Pay Period=date, Total Vacant Hours=number, Shifted Vacant=number]),

//add a column subtracting Shifted Vacant from Total Vacant
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Shifted Vacant Hours", "Vacant Hour Change", each if [Shifted Vacant] = null then null else 
        [Total Vacant Hours]-[Shifted Vacant]),

//Remove the Shifted Vacant column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Shifted Vacant"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

***Edit for different grouping***
*If you want to have a table where the Vacant hour change is computed per employee (for each time period), then we would Group By: `Empl Number`, and write a custom aggregation to add the "Vacancy Change" column.*

The code below assumes only a single entry per customer per pay period, as you show in your example. If there might be multiple entries per employee per pay period, minor code changes will be needed.

```
let

//Change next line to reflect your actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table8"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Empl Number", Int64.Type}, {"Sched Hours", type number}, {"Budg Hours", type number}, 
        {"Vacant Hours", type number}, {"Pay Period", type date}}),

//Group by pay period and custom aggregaton to assess by Employee for each time period
//Assumes only a single entry per employee per time period
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Empl Number"}, {
        {"Calcs", (t)=> let 
            subTable = Table.FromColumns(
                    Table.ToColumns(t) & {{null} & List.RemoveLastN(t[Vacant Hours])},
                    {"Empl Number", "Sched Hours", "Budg Hours", "Vacant Hours", "Pay Period", "Shifted Vacant"}),
            #"Vacancy Change" = Table.AddColumn(subTable,"Vacant Hour Change", each [Vacant Hours] - [Shifted Vacant]),
            #"Remove Shifted" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Vacancy Change",{"Shifted Vacant"})
                    in #"Remove Shifted", 
                        type table[Empl Number=Int64.Type, Sched Hours=number, Budg Hours=number, Vacant Hours=number, 
                        Pay Period=date, Vacant Hour Change=number]
            }}),

//expand the table; set columns in proper order; remove unneeded columns
    #"Expanded Calcs" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Calcs", {"Sched Hours", "Budg Hours", "Vacant Hours", "Pay Period", "Vacant Hour Change"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Expanded Calcs",{"Empl Number", "Pay Period", "Sched Hours", "Budg Hours", "Vacant Hours", "Vacant Hour Change"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{"Sched Hours", "Budg Hours"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this gave me a great deal to study in M, which i am very unfamiliar with but for some reason it is not finding some, maybe all of my columns. without sharing the server location, I cant exactly see what is wrong. I recreated a separate table to mimic this and when i source = this simple table it works just as you show. Unfortunately, I cant get this M code to find the columns. 

"Expression.Error: The column 'pay period' of the table wasn't found.
Details:
     pay period"

Comment: @StevenLeeRad `pay period` <> `Pay Period`. `M` is case-sensitive.  And in my code, I always used `Pay Period`.  Did you change something? What is the very first step (right hand panel) that returns the error?

Comment: Also, this is on me, as my desired outcome did not show this but i also need to be able to breakdown the vacant hour change by pay period and employee number. Would i just add another group by?

Comment: @StevenLeeRad Let's get the existing code running first.

Comment: It worked!   I don't know why it didn't work on the original table but when I reference the table and source only has to reference to the table name, the algorithm works. So now i need to add the position id (a column i didnt include in the example i created above but for our purposes it works the same as the Employee Number. What would the code read to add Employee Number in the breakdown?
The table columns would read: pay period / employee id / total vacant hours / vacant hour change

Comment: @StevenLeeRad I am not at my computer so cannot check this right now. I think you would want to group by both pay period and employee ID, and then compute the vacant hour change within the group by aggregation.

Comment: I was able to get it all to load back into power bi but when trying to validate by pay period and employee id it was not working. Not sure if that's due to the group addition.

Comment: #"Shifted Vacant Hours" = Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(#"Grouped Rows") & {{null} & List.RemoveLastN(#"Grouped Rows"[vacant hours],1)},
        type table[pay period=date, position number=number, Total Vacant Hours=number, Shifted Vacant=number]),

Comment: @StevenLeeRad I'll take a look this evening when I'm back at my computer.

Comment: @StevenLeeRad I've edited the code. See if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

try to create a new table

Modelling --> New Table

```
previous pay period using dax = SUMMARIZE (
    'Table',
    'Table'[Pay Period],
    "Sum Vacant", SUM ( 'Table'[Vacant Hours ] ),
    "Balance Vacant",
        SUM ( 'Table'[Vacant Hours ] )
            - CALCULATE (
                SUM ( 'Table'[Vacant Hours ] ),
                FILTER (
                    ALL ( 'Table' ),
                    'Table'[Pay Period]
                        = CALCULATE (
                            MAX ( 'Table'[Pay Period] ),
                            FILTER (
                                ALL ( 'Table' ),
                                'Table'[Pay Period] < SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Pay Period] )
                            )
                        )
                )
            )
)
```

[image: result]

Comment: I do like the path of this solution as I am more familiar with the commands, but one issue, is that i need the change from one pay period to the next and the 'Balance' appears to be a running total. Not strictly a change from one pay period to the next.

Comment: @StevenLeeRad then your question and expected result is wrong. Revise your question and expected result.